# Jquery Mobile Alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement slider as implemented in 
http://m.shaadi.com/mobile/profile/photo?profileid=JSH15485732

I noticed that they have used jquery mobile (compressed size is approx 42kb).
+ other jquery-mob extensions(+8kb)

Is there any stand alone api which can  provide me exact replica of this slider with using this heavy jquery-mobile.

Note: I can use jquery,

Comment: An exact replica? why not use it as it is then? Or use http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ to build your own. Btw. give a better example. Dont want to register some page to see.

Comment: i just need a slider moving from right to left.
Nice builder tool, can u suggest me what to choose for slider from the list